# Language for an eBay auto lister?

Tags: javascript, python, programming-languages, scripting-language

If I wanted to create an eBay auto lister, what language would this be most feasible? Python, JavaScript? Which is easiest or most efficient?

The program would need to interact with the website and input data from answers the user gives in the program’s UI. It potentially may have to move/click the mouse.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java, .Net, and Python already have an API built by eBay for exactly what you want.
You can find those here: https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/guides/ebayfeatures/ProductOverview.html#eBaySDKs

But any language that can effectively create and manipulate XML files should meet your needs.